# Rotativa ViewAsPdf, Font size change when published to server

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, fonts, pdf-generation, rotativa

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC. I have a problem when using Rotativa to rendering a Pdf page by ViewAsPdf function. It's work fine on Visual Studio debugging, but when published to localhost IIS font size was changed, It's bigger on IIS.
I have compared to HTML page without ViewAsPdf function and no problem, font size does not change, it's changed when I'm using Rotativa.

Here is Controller code:

```
return new ViewAsPdf(TempData["gridData"])
        {
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
            PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
            CustomSwitches = string.Format("--footer-left \"Note:.....\" "
                                + "--footer-font-size \"8\" "
                                + "--footer-right \"Page [page] of [toPage]\" ")
        };
```

This my View code for rendering pdf page:

```
@model IEnumerable<PM_Calibration.ViewModels.CalibrationDataList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Monthly List of Calibration Task";
    Layout = null;
}
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/PrintStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
@{
    IList<PM_Calibration.ViewModels.CalibrationDataList> ModelList = Model.ToList();
    List<PM_Calibration.ViewModels.CalibrationDataList> TableList = new List<PM_Calibration.ViewModels.CalibrationDataList>();
    var i=1;
    for (int x = 0; x < ModelList.Count; x++ )
    {
        var item = ModelList[x];
        TableList.Add(ModelList[x]);
        if(i==24)
        {
            @Html.Partial("PartialMonthlyCalibration_Table", TableList)
            i = 0;
            TableList.Clear();
        }
        i++;
    }
}
</body>
```

I'm not sure is these code enough for this question.

My question is why my font size was changed on localhost IIS?

Comment: is there a difference in CSS files between the server and dev env?

Comment: I have checked and it has same code, I have published entire project to server.

Comment: Have you found an solution to this yet? I have the same issue, and actually prefer the larger font that happens after deployment. I am running IIS Express for development.